# Sqlite database query - How to delete first carriage return in text in a column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a very large sqlite database that has a column of thousands of rows in a text column. The issue is that there is a carriage return at the beginning of every text cell.

For example, in row 1 of AssetFront (text), it has the following text:
*Carriage return* (In the database, it's just a blank line, but used this for show)
Which of the following are important to know about:

1 - Knowledge

2 - Language

3 - Art

4 - History

I could search through the entire database and delete all of the carriage returns, but that would mess up the format of the rest of the database. I just need to delete the first carriage return of each row.

Does anyone know a sql query that can do this?  I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query would remove only *first* newline `\n` from text field:

```
SELECT substr(text,2)
FROM mytable
WHERE text LIKE X'0A' || '%'
```

Use this to update data in-place:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET text = substr(text,2)
WHERE text LIKE X'0A' || '%';
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5c8f2/6)**.